# call model from within self model in django

Tags: python, django

I want to access to self model from within same model:
i want get and show all parent of each category item(if exist)

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)
    parent_id = models.ForeignKey("Category")
    ref_id = models.CharField(...)

    def __unicode__(self):
        p1 = None
        p2 = None
        p3 = None
        final = ''

        p3 = self
        if p3.parent_id:
            p2 = self.__class__.objects.get(id=p3.parent_id)
            if p2.parent_id:
                p1 = self.__class__.objects.get(id=p2.parent_id)
                final = smart_text('{}-{}-{}').format(p1.title,p2.title,p3.title)
            else:
                final = smart_text('{}-{}').format(p2.title,p3.title)
        else:
            final = smart_text('{}').format(p3.title)

        return final
```

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Category(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(...)
    parent_id = models.ForeignKey('Category',null=True,blank=True)
    ref_id = models.CharField(...)

    def __unicode__(self):
    if self.parent_id:
        return self.get_title()
    return self.title

    def get_title(self):
        title = '%s-%s'%(self.title,self.parent_id.title)
        parent = self.parent_id
        while True:
            if parent.parent_id:
                title+= '-%s'%parent.parent_id.title
                parent = parent.parent_id
            break
        return title
```

Answer (score 0):

There were some conceptual level mistakes!

If you want to create a *foreign key* field, **Django automatically adds _id to the field name while saving it in the database**. So your foreign_key's name should not contain _id, name it simply *parent*

So your model should be:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self')    # column name in the db: parent_id
```

Second thing, when selecting the foreign_key of an instance, it returns the actual instance, and not it's id. Example (using above model):

```
c = Category.objects.get(id=1)
c_parent = c.parent    # will be the instance of parent, not parent's id
c_parent_id = c.parent_id   # = c.parent.id, actual id of parent
```

So your final model can be:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self')

def __unicode__(self):
    p1 = p2 = p3 = None
    final = ''
    p3 = self
    p2 = p3.parent
    if p2:
        p1 = p2.parent
        if p1:
            final = smart_text('{}-{}-{}').format(p1.title, p2.title, p3.title)
        else:
            final = smart_text('{}-{}').format(p2.title, p3.title)
    else:
        final = smart_text('{}').format(p3.title)
    return final
```

---

In case you can't change your model now (though I'd recommend changing it asap), then this is what's happening:

- your *parent_id* field name in the database will be *parent_id_id*
- your `self.parent_id` actually refers to parents instance (use `self.parent_id_id` for actual id)

Nevertheless you shouldn't actually need parent's id, you can simply get the parent as `self.parent_id`, which you are ultimately trying to find.

Comment: You say right but,i want an instance of self model that i can filter objects

Comment: You can filter over a queryset. But the `self` would be a single instance! You cannot filter over a single instance.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid i want a way that i can call self model and filter objects again for example filter by title or filter by id and etc.

Comment: you mean something like this?  `self.__class__.objects.filter(title=x)`

Comment: yes,but it return error "int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Category'"

Comment: Can you please tell what are you trying to accomplish? Because it seems your code should fail due to recursion.

Comment: @masooddjango https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.